# Query to get the number of times an item appears

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table like this in my db:

```
id --- owner ---  product ---- type
0  --- john  ---  mustang ---- car
1  --- tim   ---  a360    ---- plane
2  --- john  ---  camry   ---- car
3  --- dan   ---  a380    ---- plane
4  --- tim   ---  ninja   ---- bike
5  --- dan   ---  accord  ---- car
```

I'm trying to get the number of each type an owner has. Something like this:

```
John 
Car = 2
Plane = 0
Bike = 0
-------------
Tim
Car = 0
Plane = 1
Bike = 1
-------------
Dan
Car = 1
Plane = 1
Bike = 0
-------------
```

I have been unable to solve this.

Another issue is that my database is able to accept new types. For example, someone can add a bicycle as a type.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused, OP. The accepted answer doesn't give the result set you said was expected in the question. What are you actually looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, first you have to generate the output rows and then get the counts:

```
select o.owner, p.product, count(t.owner)
from (select distinct owner from table) o cross join
     (select distinct product from table) p left join
     table t
     on t.owner = o.owner and t.product = p.product
group by o.owner, p.product;
```

If you have reference tables for owners and products, then you can use these instead of the `select distinct` subqueries.

EDIT:

Grouping by type is basically the same idea:

```
select o.owner, ty.type, count(t.owner)
from (select distinct owner from table) o cross join
     (select distinct type from table) ty left join
     table t
     on t.owner = o.owner and t.type = ty.type
group by o.owner, ty.type;
```

Comment: This doesn't give the result set OP was looking for.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . First, in what way?  And second, the OP accepted the answer.

Comment: OP wanted them grouped by type, not product. I can't speak to why OP accepted this, because it is inconsistent with what they asked for, so I don't know what OP really wanted here.

Answer (score 1):

The way I approached this was a little tricky.

I started by creating one result set that used a cartesian product to get one row for each person and type combination.

```
SELECT m.owner, t.type
FROM myTypes t, myTable m
GROUP BY m.owner, t.type
```

Then, I made another result set that grabbed the owner, type, and the number of each type for that owner. However, this only returned rows for existing owner-type combinations. It would not return any values for say 'John' and 'Plane' because he does not have a plane product.

```
SELECT m.owner, t.type, COUNT(*) as numOfType
FROM myTypes t
JOIN myTable m ON t.type = m.type
GROUP BY t.type, m.owner;
```

Finally, I joined those two tables together using an outer join so I received every row from the owner-type combinations table. Of course, some rows returned null for the count, so I had to use `IFNULL` to replace them with 0. This matches the result set in your question.

```
SELECT w1.owner, w1.type, IFNULL(w2.numOfType, 0) AS numOfType
FROM (SELECT m.owner, t.type
   FROM myTypes t, myTable m
   GROUP BY m.owner, t.type) w1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.owner, t.type, COUNT(*) as numOfType
   FROM myTypes t
   JOIN myTable m ON t.type = m.type
   GROUP BY t.type, m.owner) w2
ON w1.owner = w2.owner AND w1.type = w2.type;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f242cc/21).